# Merge Google fusion tables via GQL api

Tags: google-visualization, google-fusion-tables, gql

Is it possible to merge Google Fusion Tables using GQL or other Javascript/REST API?

I see how to do it manually via the application interface (i.e. select `Merge` from the menubar), but wonder if that can be done programmatically?  Presumably the app itself is doing that via some web-based API, but don't know if that's hidden or one that's intended to be publicly accessible.

Ideal would be dynamically `SELECT...` but even `CREATE TABLE...` would be fine.

[Fusion Tables Help topic on merge](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171254)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEW answer:

The [new Fusion Tables API is public](http://developers.google.com/fusiontables/), and supports programmatic merge.

OLD answer: 
The currently-public Fusion Tables SQL API does not support programmatic merge. However, the new Javascript API under Trusted Tester does support it.

You can join the TT program by applying for membership in [this Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-api-trusted-testers).

-Rebecca